# Как вывести строки с фильтром по дате за последние N дней?

Tags: mysql

Не пойму где ошибка, хочу вывести список людей которые не сдали книги в течении 10 дней. В результате выводит всех.

```
SELECT date_due_for_return, users_user_id, date_issued, date_returned
FROM Books_out_on_loan
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id =   Books_out_on_loan.Users_user_id
WHERE data_issued +10 < curdate() 
  AND date_returned is null;
```

Comment: ```WHERE data_issued +10 < curdate()``` Судя по тому, что сравнение выполняется с текущей датой, `data_issued` имеет тип DATE, DATETIME или TIMESTAMP. Поскольку контекст выражения числовой, то дата либо дата-время переводятся в числовой формат. Само собой при сложении получается ерунда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT date_due_for_return, users_user_id, date_issued, date_returned 
FROM Books_out_on_loan 
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = Books_out_on_loan.Users_user_id 
WHERE data_issued < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 10 DAY
  AND date_returned IS NULL;
```